# 3 side by side divs won't stack vertically when viewed on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have three divs which sit side by side (on a monitor), each with a background image (via CSS) and text floating on top of each background (via html). These three divs are surrounded by a container div which centers all three on the page. I want these divs to stack vertically  when viewed on a mobile device. Any suggestions? Here's the test page: http://worddiva.com.s40758.gridserver.com/?page_id=649

**Here's the html** (CSS is below):

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:744px;">
<div style="float: left; width: 248px;">
<div id="parchment">
<img id="parchmentbg" src="http://worddiva.com.s40758.gridserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Parchment-Grade-Orange.png"/>
<p id="text">
<span class="storytellingorange"><strong>Editorial</strong></span>
– Credit Union
– Wine &amp; Travel
– Arts &amp; Letters
– Alternative Energy
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 248px;">
<div id="parchment">
<img id="parchmentbg" src="http://worddiva.com.s40758.gridserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Parchment-Grade-Orange.png"/>
<p id="text">
<span class="storytellingorange"><strong>Editorial</strong></span>
– Credit Union
– Wine &amp; Travel
– Arts &amp; Letters
– Alternative Energy
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 248px;">
<div id="parchment">
<img id="parchmentbg" src="http://worddiva.com.s40758.gridserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Parchment-Grade-Orange.png"/>
<p id="text">
<span class="storytellingorange"><strong>Editorial</strong></span>
– Credit Union
– Wine &amp; Travel
– Arts &amp; Letters
– Alternative Energy
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
#parchment
{
    height:133px;
    width: 744px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#parchmentbg
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#text
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    line-height: 1.3em;  
    left:10px;
    top:-15px;
}
```

Comment: Check out [@media](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) types. This will allow you to create rules for specific screen sizes and types

Answer (score 0):

The parent div of `#parchment` has a fixed width. This causes the child divs not to stack on each other because the parent div is not getting smaller.